# HAProxy causes pending requests randomly

Tags: haproxy

I have 1 domain with 3 IP Addresses. Each address (1 server) has a HAProxy server installed. Apart from HAProxy, each server has 10 nodejs processes run.

The problem is that there are around 40% of requests are pending. Sometimes the request is processed very quick (around 160ms), sometimes it takes around 5s and even timeout. The server load is pretty low (all 8 cores run about 30%), load average is 2

I did some google and figure out that I might have run out of port for HAProxy to accept connections (I am not really sure about that)

I run `ss -s`, and the output is

```
Total: 69452 (kernel 69571)
TCP:   106031 (estab 67813, closed 36404, orphaned 570, synrecv 0, timewait 36264/0), ports 0

 Transport Total     IP        IPv6
 *    69571     -         -        
 RAW      0         0         0        
 UDP      15        9         6        
 TCP      69627     69620     7         
 INET     69642     69629     13       
 FRAG     0         0         0
```

And my `sysctl.conf`

```
vm.overcommit_memory = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2
kernel.shmmax = 17179869184
kernel.shmall = 4194304
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1025 65000
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 3240000
net.core.somaxconn = 3240000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000
net.core.rmem_default = 8388608
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = cubic
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15
```

I also try to connect directly to each app server and see if it is the app that causes the pending requests. But it is not because of the app server, it still responds super fast when I connect directly to the app server

I have enabled log and I will update the haproxy look as soon as I can

Update: I have gathered some info about the slow requests http://pastebin.com/wvApfi6E

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that I have reached the speed limit of the network interface. After upgrading, everything is back to normal